# jQuery : Set a selected option only if there is no selected option

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have an AJAX form which adds in my DB some datas and then I add them in all the selects of my form (without refreshing the page). The problem is that I want to set the new value as a selected option ONLY IF there isn't yet a selected value in the select.

**My HTML Code :**

```
<select name="Groupement[groupe][]" class="Groupement_groupe form-control">
   <option value=""></option>
   <option disabled>──────────</option>
   <option value="1">test 1</option>
   <option value="2">test 2</option>
</select>
```

**jQuery :**

I've tried this but the value is set as a selected option in every selects :

```
$('.Groupement_groupe').append($('<option>', {
                    value: datasplit[2],
                    text: 'test',
                    selected: true
                }));
```

I also tried this but it works only for the new selects (generated by javascript after the ajax form) :

```
$('.Groupement_groupe').prepend('<option value="'+datasplit[2]+'">'test'</option>');
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use [`val(function)`](http://api.jquery.com/val/#val-function) which loops through the collection and provides access to current value for each one. If there is a current value return that or return the new option value if there isn't one

```
$('.Groupement_groupe').append(
  $('<option>', {
    value: datasplit[2],
    text: 'test'    
  })
).val(function(_, currVal){
    return currVal ? currVal : datasplit[2];
});
```

Or use `filter()` to filter only selects with no value and set new value on them

```
$('.Groupement_groupe').append(
  $('<option>', {
    value: datasplit[2],
    text: 'test'    
  })
).filter(function(){
    return !this.value;
}).val(datasplit[2]);
```